# Openshift inter-gear communication

Tags: php, node.js, openshift

I'm developing an app at OpenShift which consists on a node.js gear and a php gear.

The node.js gear must communicate with the php one, so for now, in node.js i'm just doing a normal http request to the php gear.

But I read there is a routable IP to intercomunicate gears through port 8080 using HTTP (https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/intra-gear-instance-communications) but have no clue on how to get that IP.

I have looked at env vars but there is nothing and using the domain name or the loopback IP does not connect on port 8080.

Any idea on how to get that IP or what i'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm also looking into doing something like that.

Comment: Nope, did not found a solution, I'm still calling to the external domain...